# Mock object of super class in subclass using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

I have a class to be tested which is like this:

```
public class MainClass extends BaseClass {

    public static int variableToBeAsserted= 0;

    MainClass(ConfigClass config) {
        super(config);
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        List list = objectOfClass1inSuperClass.operation(objectOfClass2inSuperClass.method())
        while(methodInSuperClass()) {
            // doing operations with 'list'
            variableToBeAsserted++;
        }
    }

    // ..few other methods which I am not going to test.
}
```

I have suppressed the constructor of my `BaseClass` and my `ConfigClass`. Now my test class is like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MainClass.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        suppress(constructor(BaseClass.class))
        suppress(constructor(ConfigClass.class))
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod(){
        MainClass main = new MainClass(new ConfigClass(""));

        List list1= new ArrayList();
        test1.add("somevalues");

        Class1inSuperClass ob1 = PowerMock.createMock(Class1inSuperClass.class);
        Class2inSuperClass ob2 = PowerMock.createMock(Class2inSuperClass.class);

        EasyMock.expect(ob2.method()).andReturn(getClass());
        EasyMock.expect(ob1.operation(getClass())).andReturn(list1);

        PowerMock.replayAll();
        main.myMethod();

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, main.variableToBeAsserted);    
    }
}
```

Now I don't know why but my test case fails with a `NullPointerException`.

It tries to access `objectofClass1inSuperClass` and fails. I thought this will mock it. But it does not get mocked.

**EDIT:** I am writing only the test and I cannot change anything in `BaseClass`. However I have the option to modify the `MainClass`.

Comment: Please, correct me if I wrong. That's how I understand your case: in constructor of the `BaseClass` the fields `objectOfClass1inSuperClass` and `objectOfClass2inSuperClass`are initialised. You suppress constructor  `BaseClass` to avoid such behaviour. But why do you suppress `ConfigClass`constructor? Also I see that you create mocks, but never inject/set it.

Comment: Even the `configClass` constructor initialises some classes which I do not want to use. Hence I am supressing it. Yes, that is what I want to know.How to inject the mocks in my actual object

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to inject mock object to the object under the test.

Manually via `WhiteBox`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MainClass.class)
public class WhiteBoxApproachTestClass {

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    suppress(constructor(BaseClass.class));
  }


  @Test
  public void testMyMethod() {
    MainClass main = new MainClass(createMock(ConfigClass.class));

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("somevalues");

    Class1inSuperClass ob1 = createMock(Class1inSuperClass.class);
    Class2inSuperClass ob2 = createMock(Class2inSuperClass.class);

    expect(ob2.method()).andReturn(getClass());
    expect(ob1.operation(getClass())).andReturn(list1);

    Whitebox.setInternalState(main, "objectOfClass1inSuperClass", ob1);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(main, "objectOfClass2inSuperClass", ob2);

    replayAll();

    main.myMethod();

    assertThat(MainClass.variableToBeAsserted).isEqualTo(5);
  }
}
```

And via `@TestSubject` (http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-annotations)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MainClass.class)
public class TestSubjectApproachTestClass {

  @Mock(fieldName = "objectOfClass1inSuperClass")
  private Class1inSuperClass ob1;

  @Mock(fieldName = "objectOfClass2inSuperClass")
  private Class2inSuperClass ob2;

  @TestSubject
  private final MainClass main = new MainClass(createMock(ConfigClass.class));

  @BeforeClass
  public static void before() throws Exception {
    suppress(constructor(BaseClass.class));
  }

  @Test
  public void testMyMethod() {

    List<String> list1= new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("somevalues");

    expect(ob2.method()).andReturn(getClass());
    expect(ob1.operation(getClass())).andReturn(list1);

    EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(main);

    replayAll();

    main.myMethod();

    assertThat(MainClass.variableToBeAsserted).isEqualTo(5);
  }
}
```

Full code you may find [here](https://github.com/thekingnothing/stackoverflow/tree/master/q38502419).